# Searching for a NaN strike

Tags: python, nan

I have a Dataframe in which some columns contain wrong information. This wrong information is always before a longer sequence of NaN values. Let's imagine I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd 
from numpy import nan

d = {'Obs1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'Obs2': [0.1, 0.1, nan, nan, nan, nan, 100, 101]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

"Obs1" is without wrong information, while "Obs2" has wrong values before the 4-NaN sequence. Does anyone know how to find such a longer sequence in a timeseries (e.g. an occurence of 4 NaN values), to then fill all previous entries with NaN? To give an example, my desired Output would be:

```
Output = {'Obs1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'Obs2': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 100, 101]}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'strike'?  2) Can you please provide an example of the output you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each column, check the i'th element and (i+1)'th element are NaN and find max index (i) satisfying the i'th element and (i+1)'th element are NaN.

See the following code.

```
for col in df.columns:
    cond = df[col].iloc[1:].isnull() + df[col].iloc[:-1].isnull() == 2
    if sum(cond) >= 2:    
        df[col].iloc[:cond.index[-1] - 1] = nan
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this works if I am searching for sequences between 2 and more nan's, but what if I want to search specifically e.g. for 20 nan after each other?

Comment: Then change "if sum(cond) >= 2" to "if sum(cond) >= 20"